# python3 vlc module - no audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, vlc

I am running python3 with the vlc module version `python-vlc==3.0.4106`.

When I run the following python3 script I get no audio:

```
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("/path/to/music.mp3")
p.play()
```

When I run that script I get no output, no errors, no audio.

When I play the mp3 on the command line using cvlc is plays fine.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It works on my side, maybe your audio file has some special? Try change a mp3 file & narrow down the issue.

Comment: @iagom it works for you, that is interesting. I have tried different files, wav, flac, etc. Still no audio.

Comment: So, maybe different environment issue, os? python-vlc version? Terminal category etc, you need to update what's your environment? My workable is on: windows 10, python-vlc==3.0.4106

Comment: @iagom we're using the same version. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the program is terminating before it can even play the audio file. if you change the code to:

```py
import time 
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///music.flac")
p.play()
time.sleep(10)
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever use p.audio_set_volume(100) there is a chance of the player is muted so just set it back to 100.Use the following code...

```
import vlc,time
#Specifie your path for the song
p = vlc.MediaPlayer(r"C:\Users\dell5567\Desktop\engsong\Dire-Straits-Walk-Of-Life.mp3")
p.play()
#Sets the volume to 100
p.audio_set_volume(100)
time.sleep(10)
```